# Flutter CupertinoTabBar overlays webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am using `WebView` on some pages and CupertinoTabBar is overlapping my `WebView`, how can i fix this without using padding?

```
class _ShoppingBagState extends State<ShoppingBag> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Constants.USER_TOKEN.isEmpty ?
      const Center(
        child: Text('Авторизуйтесь', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      )
     :
      Stack(
        children: [
         WebView(),
          Visibility(
            visible: isLoading,
            child: const Positioned.fill(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )),
          )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to wrap the `WebView` in a `SafeArea` to solve the problem